# Installation of [copybook] failed

Tags: python, anaconda, copybook

I am trying to use the python module `copybook` in my conda environment. However, I keep getting the `PackagesNotFoundError`. I have also downloaded the package from github, but had no luck installing that. Would you have any recommendations?

I tried running: `conda install copybook`

And got this error:

```
.... PackagesNotFoundError

downloaded files into folder [copybook-master]
tried: python setup.py
got: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\wmetzner\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpr1pfsztd', '--quiet', 'pytest-runner']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```